# Prove $a/b$ is an algebraic number

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a$ and $b$ be algebraic numbers, with $b\ne0$. Show using resultants, that $a/b$ is also an algebraic number. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: You show that the resultant of two appropriate polynomials has $\frac{b}{a}$ as a root. This is covered nicely in the wikipedia page for resultant (under applications).

Comment: Yes I figured that I need a resultant with (x-b/a) as a factor. But the problem is which polynomials do I use. I have the proof for a+b is algebraic but I can't figure out how I should adapt that argument in this case?

Comment: @Richard: I fear you have maybe a mistake when you say you have the proof for $a+b$ . Try to apply your result to the sum of $\sqrt[5]7$ plus $\sqrt[7]5$. My opinion is that your question here is not in general solvable. Fortunately we know that the algebraic numbers form a field, so $\frac ab$ is algebraic.

Comment: @Piquito What do you mean?  [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Applications) tells you exactly how to compute such a polynomial.

Comment: @Richard $a$ and $b$ are algebraic, hence satisfy polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.  Use the resultant results of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Applications) with those polynomials.

Comment: @SpamIAm: I mean that for individual and concrete cases the problem can be hard or impossible. In abstract theory it is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a$ and $b$ are algebraic, $[\mathbb Q(a),\mathbb Q]$ and $[\mathbb Q(b):\mathbb Q]$ are finite. In particular, $\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb Q(a,b)$ and 
$$[\mathbb Q(a,b):\mathbb Q]\leq [\mathbb Q(a):\mathbb Q][\mathbb Q(b):\mathbb Q].$$
Therefore $[\mathbb Q(a,b):\mathbb Q]$ is finite, and thus $\mathbb Q(a,b)$ is algebraic. In particular, $\frac{a}{b}$ is also algebraic.

Comment: That's obvious. I need to prove it using resultants.